# PHP open pdf and redirect with header

Tags: php, redirect, header

I'm using fpdf for create a pdf, this works correctly, the problem is, I need to use header to redirect in determined php file, but doesn't work.

```
 //Report.php
 //data in pdf created correctly.
 $pdf->close();
 //without ob_end_clean, the pdf doesn't show
 ob_end_clean();
 $pdf->Output($file,'I');
 //return to index.php
 header("Location: ".DOL_URL_ROOT.'/product/stock/index.php');
```

Hi, what I need is:

- 1 Create and fill pdf, DONE.
- 2 Display or download pdf, DONE
- 3 Redirect to antoher page, PENDING, this is the part is not working.

Thanks

Comment: `$pdf->Output($file,'I');` will display the file, so the redirect makes no sense

Comment: you cant display and redirect. if you redirect they wont see the pdf. your logic makes no sense

Comment: This is the problem, in this program, after save a transaction, you need receive a pdf, and later, return to main page, so, I really don't know how can this achieve, because only $pdf->output(), doesn't work. can you suggest another way?

Comment: save pdf on server, redirect to main page. serve pdf from main page so then after they download it they will still be on main page.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the header call. 
pdf->output($file,'I') will anyhow display the newly created file.

Comment: Hi, I need redirect after pdf is created, but it's not working,